# Regular expression doesn't start with character and followed by specific pattern in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I need help in finding a string which doesn't start with a certain string and 2nd part should contain specific string anywhere and should contain 4 dots

Currently i'm doing it this way. Need a better way to do it

`table_name like '%.%.%.%'  AND table_name not like 'click%' AND split(table_name,'\\\\.')[1] rlike 'click'`

Sample Data

```
catalog.aw_click_567.fact.empl      -- This should come in output
sales.click.fact.profit             -- This should come in output
click_ext.aw_click_567.fact.empl    -- This shouldn't
```

I'm tried above with 3 And condition but there should be a better way with one regular expression condition